# PostgreSQL group by in loaded many to many relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, postgresql

I'm currently designing a database regarding music toplists (like a voting system).

I have the Song Entity which contains the basic song fields like title, artist, genre etc, then we have the Toplist Entity which has the name attribute, endDate and it's connected with the Song entity in a Many-To-Many relationship through the ToplistSong table which also contains the song votes for a particular toplist.

The Toplist entity:

```
export class Toplist extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany((type) => Song)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'toplist_song',
    joinColumn: { name: 'toplistId', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'songId', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
  })
  songs: Song[];

  @Column({ type: 'date', nullable: false })
  endDate: Date;
}
```

The conjuction table ToplistSong:

```
@Entity('toplist_song')
export class ToplistSong {
  @PrimaryColumn('int')
  toplistId: number;

  @PrimaryColumn('int')
  songId: number;

  @ManyToOne((type) => Toplist, { nullable: false })
  @JoinColumn()
  toplist: Toplist;

  @ManyToOne((type) => Song, { nullable: false })
  @JoinColumn()
  song: Song;

  @Column({ type: 'int', nullable: false, default: 0 })
  votes: number;
}
```

Let's say we insert 2 toplists, each of those toplists contains 3 songs:
[image: Result from the ToplistSong table]

I'd like to create a query which returns an array of toplists, where each toplist is an array of songs and the votes attribute from ToplistSong is attached to each song.

Example of how the response would look:

```
  { // The first toplist
    "id": 1,
    "name": "First toplist",
    "endDate": "2022-06-20",
    "songs": [ // array of songs which are in the current toplist
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Test Song 1",
        "genre": "Hip-Hop",
        "votes": 0 // votes attribute attached which exists in ToplistSong
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Test Song 2",
        "genre": "Hip-Hop",
        "votes": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Test Song 3",
        "genre": "Hip-Hop",
        "votes": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  { // The second toplist
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Second toplist",
    "endDate": "2022-10-20",
    "songs": [ // array of songs which are in the current toplist
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Second Test Song 1",
        "genre": "Jazz",
        "votes": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Second Test Song 2",
        "genre": "Jazz",
        "votes": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Second Test Song 3",
        "genre": "Jazz",
        "votes": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Regarding the database design overall, I think this approach is good but I am open to other approaches as well. If this design seems good, I'd like some help creating a query which would help me get that response :)

Thanks for any help provided in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to join the toplist with song data. Left join is used because I presume `toplist` may have no songs first:

```
SELECT 
  jsonb_agg(toplists_agg.result) as result
FROM (
  SELECT
    to_jsonb(toplist) 
    || jsonb_build_object(
         'songs', 
         jsonb_agg(
           to_jsonb(song) 
           || jsonb_build_object('votes', toplistsong.votes)
         )
     ) as result
  FROM toplist
    LEFT JOIN toplistsong ON toplistid = toplist.id
    LEFT JOIN song ON song.id = toplistsong.songid
  GROUP BY
    toplist.*
) toplists_agg
;
```

You may try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-LvrAXZM)